# Markov chain plot. How to hide probabilities in the plot

Tags: r, igraph, markov

I have a huge matrix and I'm trying to visualize it better. I only found edge.arrow.size, vertex.size and layout to include in the details of the plot, but it still is hard to visualize
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try

```
plot(g, edge.label = NA)
```

if you want to disable edge labels.

Comment: It didn't change anything.

Comment: @DanielCordeiro Could you `dput` your data?